# Lenovo G50 fails to boot after upgrade

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, lenovo

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo G50. Everything was working fine. I haven't used that computer in about 6 months until I loaded it up last night. I did a simple apt-get upgrade and now it will not boot at all. When I try to boot, It says that the graphics card was not detected and that its running in low graphics mode. Displays a dialog box asking me what I want to do, but no option works. It either just reloads the dialog box or freezes the computer. Cant even load the terminal. I cant find my live disk, but will be making a new one latter today. Wondering if anyone know how I might be able to solve this without having to to run a live disk as I seem to be more or less lockout of everything.

Is there anything I can do to save it without having to reinstall the entire OS? Has anyone encountered this error before? If so, do you know what causes this?

Comment: Have you tried booting using the nomodeset parameter?

Comment: I have not, But i will defiantly try that

Comment: It did not work. I think I'm just going to have to blast the system.

Comment: K - there are a number of Q&A about "low graphics 16.04", generally related to the proprietary graphics drivers.